# MissingPropertyException: No such property: generator for class: org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, configuration

I recently moved part of the config from `application.yml` to `application.groovy` so we can use environment variables in the config. And once we did that we are getting an ugly exception. The worst part is that we are getting the same exception even if we revert everything.

I cleaned up the project, even checked out a fresh copy of the code.... nothing helps.

At this point, I have no idea where to go from here.

The exception is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: generator for class: org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at priz.Application.main(Application.groovy:13)
...
```

Here is my `application.yml`

```
---
grails:
    profile: rest-api
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: priz
    gorm:
        reactor:
            # Whether to translate GORM events into Reactor events
            # Disabled by default for performance reasons
            events: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            js: text/javascript
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            all: '*/*'
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8

---
grails:
    cors:
        enabled: true
        allowedOrigins:
          - http://localhost:4200
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false
```

and `application.groovy`

```
grails {
    plugin {
        springsecurity {
            filterChain {
                chainMap = [
                    [
                            pattern = '/v1/login',
                            filters = 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter'
                    ],
                    [
                            pattern = '/v1/api/**',
                            filters = 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
                    ]
                ]
            }
            userLookup {
                userLookup = 'User'
                authorityJoinClassName = 'UserRole'
            }
            authority {
                className = 'Role'
            }
            rest {
                token {
                    storage {
                        jwt {
                            secret = "secret"
                        }
                    }
                    validation {
                        enableAnonymousAccess = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
grails.plugin.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
   ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
'''

grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileName = 'changelog.groovy'

grails.gorm.failOnError = true
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    id generator = 'identity'
}

dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
//    dialect = "hibernate.MyPostgreSQLDialect"
    username = "sa"
    password = ''

    properties {
        jmxEnabled = true
        initialSize = 5
        maxActive = 50
        minIdle = 5
        maxIdle = 25
        maxWait = 10000
        maxAge = 600000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
        validationQueryTimeout = 3
        validationInterval = 15000
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnReturn = false
        jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
        defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    }
}

environments {
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }

    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = ""
            driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/priz"
            username = "postgres"
            password = "postgres"
            logSql = false
        }
    }

    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = ""
            pooled = true
            url = System.getenv('PRIZ_DATABASE_URL')
            driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            username = System.getenv('PRIZ_DATABASE_USER')
            password = System.getenv('PRIZ_DATABASE_PASSWORD')
            logSql = false
            properties {
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}

priz {
    auth0 {
        domain = "https://priz-dev.auth0.com"
        cache {
            size = 5
            expiresIn = 10
        }
        rateLimit {
            bucketSize = 10
            refillRate = 1
        }

        api {
            domain = "priz-dev.auth0.com"
            clientId = "secret"
            clientSecret = "secret"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `grails.gorm.default.mapping = { id column: 'id', generator: 'identity' }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it should be:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = { 
   id column: 'id', generator: 'identity' 
}
```